# How to get the text from disabled textbox using selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Provided that particular element doesn't have any attributes to make use of.

Comment: Show us the HTML.

Comment: Bycss `input[type='text']:disabled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value attribute stores the content of a tag, does not matter whether it is disabled or not. So, you can do it like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("write_element_id_here")).getAttribute("value");
```

This will return you the value of the element and then you can proceed with the rest. Hope it helps..